# I'm trying to make an (if , else) statement but it does not work

Tags: java, sqlite, if-statement, netbeans

I'm making a small program that needs a login
I'm using  SQLite as a database and working with NetBeans ide
the first (if, else statement) here is to ensure that the user does not leave the text field or the password field empty and it does not work
the second (if, else statement) is to check if the password and username are in the database and its working fine
here is my code::

````
private void btnloginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  
if(jTextField1.getText()== "" || jPasswordField1.getText()=="")
{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "the usernmae or bassword filed is empty");}

else {
     String sql = "SELECT * from Accounts WHERE User LIKE ? AND pass LIKE ? ; ";
    try{
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jPasswordField1.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
                
        if (rs.next()){
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"log in successful");
            
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new booking().setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            }
        });
                    
                      }
        else 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, " wrong username or password ");
            
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "error "+e);
    
    }} ```
````

Comment: These conditions are invalid. You need to use the equal method in the String jTextField1.getText().equal("") || jPasswordField1.getText().equal("")

Comment: If you get your IDE to format your code (i.e. get the indentation consistent), I think you'll find it a lot easier to understand then code and then spot the problem. (That's in addition to using equals - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832)

Comment: Format the code

Answer (score 1):

These conditions are invalid. You need to use the equal method in the String

```
jTextField1.getText().equal("") || jPasswordField1.getText().equal("")
```

Or you can use

```
jTextField1.getText().isEmpty() || jPasswordField1.getText().isEmpty()
```

More info here:

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-equals-method-in-java/#:~:text=We%20can%20use%20%3D%3D%20operators,of%20values%20in%20the%20objects](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-equals-method-in-java/#:%7E:text=We%20can%20use%20%3D%3D%20operators,of%20values%20in%20the%20objects).

Answer (score 0):

Best approach first save those username and password in string object.

```
String username=jTextField1.getText();
String password=jPasswordField1.getText();
```

Now compare them with null and length.

```
if((username!=null && username.length>0) || (password!=null && password.length>0)){
//write sql query
}else{
//error message
}
```